# How to show both the bottom and the top border of a cell in iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, itext

I am very new in **iTextSharp** (the iText porting for C#) and I am going crazy with the followint situation.

In the application that I am working on I have a table definied in this way:

```
table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.SetWidths(new int[] { 100, 500 });
//table.WidthPercentage = 95;

table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Description:")) { Border = PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER, Padding = 5, MinimumHeight = 50, PaddingTop = 15 });

table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(currentVuln.ShortSummary)) { Border = PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER, Padding = 5, MinimumHeight = 50, PaddingTop = 15 });
_document.Add(table);
```

s you can see a new cell is add to the table creating it passing to it the string that have to show in itself and after passing some grphical settings.

For example:

```
table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Description:")) { Border = PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER, Padding = 5, MinimumHeight = 50, PaddingTop = 15 });
```

it add a new cell that show the string **Description** and the graphical settings into the {...} block are applied.

My first doubt is: what exactly is this syntax? is it a C# syntax or it is something related to iTextSharp?

Thene I am going crazy to understand what exactly happen when this settings are applied in particular when it is evaluate this section: **Border = PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER**

1) Border is an int value into the **iTextSharp.text.Rectangle** class that take the value of **PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER** returned value

2) **PdfCell** is another class that is into the **iTextSharp.text.pdf** namespace and it don't contains the **BOTTOM_BORDER** property but this class is definied in this way:

```
public class PdfPCell : Rectangle, IAccessibleElement
```

So the **PdfCell** class is itself a **Rectangle** and the **BOTTOM_BORDER** property is into **Rectangle** class, infact here I have

```
public const int BOTTOM_BORDER = 2;
```

Ok...so I think that doing:

**Border = PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER** is the same thing that do: **Border = 2** that sets a specific type of border to my cell. Is it right?

The doubt is: why I have to pass to the PdfPCell class (that is a Rectangle) to set the border and I don't set it directly on **Rectangle**?

I have also the following problem: by **Border = PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER** I show only the bottom border of a cell, what can I do to show the bottom and the upper bord of a cell?

Tnx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

More than likely it is flag based.

Give this a shot:

```
Border = PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER | PdfPCell.TOP_BORDER
```

Comment: how to put the border of bottom to every page's end pdfcell, so it look like a close box on every page

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use numbers from 0 to 15

0 no border
1 top border
2 bottom border
.
.
.
9 left and right border
.
.
and so on